# Use Oracle 10g Express for ASP Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle10g

My brother is currently learning ASP.NET in his college. They taught him ASP.NET Membership provider today and it works fine until you have SQL Express, but I would like to know is it possible to use it with Oracle 10g?

I found a link for Oracle Providers for ASP.NET but they are for version 11. Anything like same for 10g?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the 11g of Oracle Express Edition?

Comment: Its part of his curriculum to use 10g..

Answer (score 0):

After some amount of searching, I stumbled upon this site, which though doesnt state clearly but following the tutorial, I was able to use 11g ASP.NET Providers with Oracle 10g also.

http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/dotnet/aspprovider/aspprovider_otn.htm

Hope it helps anybody in a similar dilemma.